# Bind in HTML with a dynamic variable

Tags: html, angular, data-binding

I've changed a value in a variable ( boolean ) and I would like to display a loader while my promise is not complete.

```
       <ng-container *ngIf="!fullyLoad">
        <mat-spinner [diameter]="13" ></mat-spinner>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="fullyLoad">cancel</mat-icon>
      </ng-container>
```

And here's my code of the component

```
 this.ranchService.getValue().then(() => {

  console.log(this.fullyLoad + ' pas encore defini ')
  this.fullyLoad = this.ranchService.fullyLoad; // normally it returns true
});
```

I put the variable `this.fullyload` to false at the beginning, but when I try to access in front, it doesn't appear while my promise is not finished.

Complete code :

```
  async getRanches(): Promise<Boolean> {

this.dataServ.get<DetailedRanchDTO[]>(DetailedRanchDTO, this.URL)
  .pipe(delay(3000)).subscribe(ranches =>

  this._ranches$.next(ranches), error => (error), () => console.log('fini'));

return true;
```

}

async getValue(): Promise {

```
await this.getRanches().then(result => {
  this.fullyLoad = result;
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console prefer-template
  console.log(this.fullyLoad + 'result');
});
```

}

Any suggest ?

Comment: you have to write the element how you want it to look on load, then on event, run yoour event listener (and piggy back the loading message) then on fulfillment, run the data. you might not be getting data back. have you examined the response in console.log()?

Comment: how do you detect if your promise fulfills?

Comment: there is a reason i am trying to get you to think of this. for example. if i call fetchAPI or AJAX, i use `.then( (results) => { /*write conditional code here*/});`

Comment: what should your answer look like? write conditional code to determine it and along with the .then parameter function, change the element you want to change.

Comment: ok, so test if your boolean is true. if it is write code to display the results and show your icon.

Comment: Ok, i just used bad words to explain it, when I call my promise this.ranchService.getValue(), I wait for the loading of an object. With the .then, i execute code which mean my loading of object is over. So, i set to true my variable. BUT the problem is not here, because first my variable is set to false, so i must have my loader no ?

Comment: try this  `this.ranchService.getValue().then(() => {

  console.log(this.fullyLoad + ' pas encore defini ')
  this.fullyLoad = this.ranchService.fullyLoad; // normally it returns true
}).catch((err) => {console.log(err)});`

Comment: it returns true, because the loading of the data is finish.

Comment: just like `.then()` waits for the response, `.catch()` waits for an error. see if there is an error, maybe youre not getting your response.

Comment: so if that code i gave you doesnt log an error, it seems like your code is getting a response ok. so you are now getting the correct response `true` now you need to display the icon. `.then( () => {/*WRITE CODE HERE TO DISPLAY ICON*/})`

Comment: you don't understand my problem lol and i surely explain not very well. I have my icon when it's loaded. It's not the problem. The problem is, while it's not finished, it doesn't display the loader

Comment: that might be the case. you have written contradicting requirement. for exmaple you want a loader in your original question, but not i your reply to my comments. post more code for better help. good luck